# SQL Server 2008 R2 filtered index

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing, filtered-index

Is there any way to investigate what I haven't used as a value during creating filtered index? I have looked at index create script but still no value.

```
create nonclustered index IX1 where status=0
```

I am looking for the status column and 0 value in below query

Comment: What is the question? SQL Server management studio can create the creation scripts for every object in the database (including indices). Did you not know that, or am I overlooking something more complex here?

Comment: yeah there is ofcourse index creat script but I am looking for what value I have put during creation of filtered index

Comment: Ok, so what is the difference between the create script and the value you did put in? Ths is like "I do not want to listen to the recording what I said, I want to know what I said". They are identical. Unless someone has changed the index in the meantime. Your question makes no sense as it is.

Comment: You put 0. 0 is the value. The value you put is 0.

Comment: I have used where clause during creation of my index(filtered) and now I dont remember what I have used during creation.

Comment: SO, have SSMS generate the creation script. Read it. It is the same you did enter.

Comment: yes, it generates but without where cause

Comment: @RemusRusanu thanks for the help, you are a great observer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in system catalog view [`sys.indexes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173760.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) has the filter information in the `filter_definition` column:

```
select
    o.name as [Table],
    i.name as [Index],
    i.filter_definition as [Filter]
from sys.objects o
inner join sys.indexes i on i.object_id = o.object_id
where i.name = 'IX1'
```

Comment: if my filter definition is null and I am sure that it is a filtered index with a value, what is the next step I should control out

Comment: I tested this with a index filter, and the filter value appeared correctly in the `filter_definition` column.  I would guess that either 1) you are using a view that has this filter, or 2) all the rows in the database are actually status = 0.

Comment: yeah you are right, I have tested in my local and it gives me the correct filter definition, I will check the reasons you listed as why it is not there

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, SQL Management Studio can script your filtered index. Just right click on your index and click `Script Index as`. However, if you want to query it using SQL, you can just select the `filter definition` column from the `sys.indexes` table:

```
 SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) ,
       t.name ,
       i.name ,
       filter_definition
 FROM   sys.indexes i
       INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
 WHERE  i.type > 0
       AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
       AND t.name <> 'sysdiagrams'
       AND ( is_primary_key = 0
            AND is_unique_constraint = 0
          )
       AND i.name = 'IX1'
```

Comment: thanks for the help but I also know what people say inside comment, people should read the question really carefully, to insult someone is so easy

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you cannot confirm the filtered index where clause because that is considered code, and you only have access to data.

See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55811/database-having-only-db-datareader-shows-invalid-properties-for-a-index

It is true that a db_datareader cannot directly confirm the filtered index where clause (sys.indexes.filter_definition), and SSMS will not warn a db_datareader that scripting the index definition will be incomplete.

However, there is a workaround that a db_datareader can use to indirectly confirm the filter_definition: specify an index hint in a query, with a where clause to test for coverage by the filtered index.

MS-SQL will throw an error, if a column or value you specify in the query where clause is NOT covered by the filtered index where clause (sys.indexes.filter_definition).

So this way, you can at least verify that the query where clause you would like to use is covered by the filtered index. You do not need to use the index hint in production, after you have verified it this way.

For example, if a filtered index is created by a db_owner like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_ZipData_PrimaryPerZip
 ON dbo.ZipData (ZIP) WHERE IsPrimaryCity = 1
```

Then as a db_datareader, I can confirm that this query works, so I have confirmed that `IsPrimaryCity = 1` is covered by the index:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Num
  FROM dbo.ZipData WITH (INDEX (NCI_ZipData_Zip))
  WHERE IsPrimaryCity = 1
```

Also as a db_datareader, I can confirm that this query fails, so I have confirmed that `IsPrimaryCity = 0` is NOT covered by the index:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Num
  FROM dbo.ZipData WITH (INDEX (NCI_ZipData_Zip))
  WHERE IsPrimaryCity = 0
```

The error message returned by MS-SQL is:

```
Msg 8622, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.
```